# Pronunciation of 옷이 with linking sound

Tags: pronunciation, spoken-korean, final-consonant

I am wondering if is there any pronunciation rule for 받침 when linking sound is involved. For example, the word 옷이 in the sentence below.

> 시장에 **옷이** 많았습니다

When we read the word 옷이 slowly (so not using linking sound - the 받침 ㅅ and the following vowel 이), the 받침 ㅅ is pronounced as ㄷ. So the word is read as 옫이. However, when we read it fast and using linking word, how would you pronounce it?

1. 오디
2. 오시

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

> When we read the word 옷이 slowly, the 받침 ㅅ is pronounced as ㄷ.

No, it's not. It's **always** pronounced [오시], no matter how slow you read it. Unless somehow the 이 part was obscured while 옷 was being read, so you couldn't infer the batchim's sound value until 이 was revealed.

Reading 옷이 as [오디] is **wrong**. You move the final consonant to the next syllable's initial position **as-is** if the next phoneme is a function morpheme and starts with a vowel.

'옷이' being pronounced as [오시] is **not** a linking sound. It's merely an orthographic quirk. You need actual sound changes in order to call something a linguistic phenomenon.

Answer (score 1):

The final consonant ㅅ **can** be pronounced as ㄷ even when followed by a vowel, but **only when** followed by a verb, another noun, adverb or adjective. Please note that this is **NOT 100% TRUE**.

Example when it is true:

맛없다 [마덥따]

옷 입다 =} 옫 입다 =} 옫 닙다 =} 온닙따

Example when it is not true:

맛있다 [마싣따]

For other words like 이, ㅅ is always pronounced as [s] when followed by a vowel since it is neither noun nor verb nor adjective nor adverb.

Comment: Wait what, 맛없다 [마덥따].  
Shouldn't it be pronounced as (맛없다) --> 마섭따 ?
You said, 
"ㅅ is always pronounced as [s] when followed by a vowel " and "없" starts with a vowel....

Comment: @Amacelia Please read the **whole** answer before giving comment

Comment: Please realize that comment was an inquiry that asked for clarification.

Comment: 1. 맛없다 is pronounced as 마덥따. Check out dictionary if you don't believe.

Comment: 2. I **never** said ㅅ is always pronounced as [s]. I said in the first sentence that ㅅ could be pronounced as [d]. You didn't read my post thoroughly.